# Strange behaviour with multiple condition IF statment

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

I've noticed, that I stumble upon a strange behavior of the if function when combining `!=` and `&&` operators. For instance, I have two `std::string` objects for which I want to check if they are not `"ffff"` or `"0000"` and then continue with some calculations.

Code looks like this:

```
std::string sentData("ffff")
std::string sentAddr("060C")
if (sentData == "ffff") 
    cout << "A 1. Same" << endl;
else 
    cout << "A 1. Different" << endl;
if (sentAddr == "0000") 
    cout << "A 2. Same" << endl;
else 
    cout << "A 2. Different" << endl;
if ((sentData == "ffff") && (sentAddr == "0000")) 
    cout << "A &&. Same" << endl;
else 
    cout << "A &&. Different" << endl;

if (sentData != "ffff") 
    cout << "B 1. Different" << endl;
else 
    cout << "B 1. Same" << endl;
if (sentAddr != "0000") 
    cout << "B 2. Different" << endl;
else 
    cout << "B 2. Same" << endl;
if ((sentData != "ffff") && (sentAddr != "0000")) 
    cout << "B &&. Different" << endl;
else 
    cout << "B &&. Same" << endl;
```

In theory, I think that it should produce the same result ... but it doesn't. The last if function treats `&&` as `||` (and I do not know why), therefore I go into the last if statement even if only one of the answers is correct. Some answers below.

Works as it should:

```
sentData: ffff  sentAddr: 0000
A 1. Same
A 2. Same
A &&. Same
B 1. Same
B 2. Same
B &&. Same

sentData: ffdf  sentAddr: 060e
A 1. Different
A 2. Different
A &&. Different
B 1. Different
B 2. Different
B &&. Different
```

Works wrong:

```
sentData: ffff  sentAddr: 060c
A 1. Same
A 2. Different
A &&. Different
B 1. Same
B 2. Different
B &&. Same

sentData: fb8c  sentAddr: 0000
A 1. Different
A 2. Same
A &&. Different
B 1. Different
B 2. Same
B &&. Same
```

So if I use `sentData: fb8c  sentAddr: 0000` in `if ((sentData != "ffff") && (sentAddr != "0000"))` I get `if (TRUE && FALSE)`, but apparently it still enters the `if` statement.

**Q:** Does anyone know why?

I am asking this because I would like to avoid writing ugly code like this:

```
if (!((sentData == "ffff") && (sentAddr == "0000"))) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
if ((sentData == "ffff") && (sentAddr == "0000")) {
    // nothing to do
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: So, basically you want to know why `x!=a&&x!=b` behaves as `!(x==a||x==b)` ? ... Draw truth tables and think a bit about it, because it's correct. Or is something else the problem?

Comment: Check De Morgan's law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws ). `!(a && b) == (!a || !b)`

Comment: _"In theory, I think that it should produce the same result"_ Can you explain why you think this?

Comment: @king_nak: Please do not answer in the comments section.

Comment: No no no, you did not understand me. I am saying that in the last `if` statment `"B &&. Different"` is printed if either one of the conditions with `!=` sign is true. But it should be printed only if both of them are true. Like so: `IF ((sentData NOT EQUAL "ffff") AND (sentAddr NOT EQUAL "0000)) { do stuff ... }` So is this De Morgan's Law or something else?
@deviantfan, no this is not what I want to know. @Lightness Races in Orbit, hopefully I explained it a bit more now (I also updated the original question)

Comment: @TheoryX "It should be printed only if both of them are true." **No, it's printed if only both of them are false.** That `B &&. Different` expression is printed `if (a or b)`, not `if (!(a and b))`. This is because `!(a and b) == (!a or !b)`.

Comment: @TheoryX Also, I think you're tripping over your idea of what "the same" means for the print statements. I think you're attempting to print out the same thing using an analogue of positive and negative logic. De Morgan's Law still holds for both.

Comment: @VermillionAzure, I have already seen my mistake yesterday, and also wrote an explanation under the 2nd answer. I would love to up vote both answers, but sadly cannot due to insufficient reputation. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be still a bit confused, I'll try with a different approach than the one taken by @VermillionAzure with his brilliant answer.

---

Consider the following source code which has the exact same *test conditions* as yours, minus irrelevant ones, but a different output description:

```
if ((sentData == "ffff") && (sentAddr == "0000")) 
    cout << "both are equal" << endl;
else 
    cout << "at least one is different" << endl;

if ((sentData != "ffff") && (sentAddr != "0000")) 
    cout << "both are different" << endl;
else 
    cout << "at least one is equal" << endl;
```

This is the output:

```
sentData: ffff  sentAddr: 0000
both are equal
at least one is equal

sentData: ffdf  sentAddr: 060e
at least one is different
both are different

sentData: ffff  sentAddr: 060c
at least one is different
at least one is equal

sentData: fb8c  sentAddr: 0000
at least one is different
at least one is equal
```

As you see, the *output* doesn't **appear** to be inconsistent anymore.

Since I didn't change any of your *test conditions* but only the printed output, it necessarily follows that the description is now *accurate* wrt. the actual meaning of your *test conditions*.

---

If you want to rewrite this

```
if ((sentData == "ffff") && (sentAddr == "0000")) 
    cout << "both are equal" << endl;
else 
    cout << "at least one is different" << endl;
```

using `!=`, then you should do it as follows:

```
if (!((sentData != "ffff") || (sentAddr != "0000"))) 
    cout << "both are equal" << endl;
else 
    cout << "at least one is different" << endl;
```

This is an example of applying [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

---

Both of these two

```
if (!((sentData == "ffff") && (sentAddr == "0000"))){
    // do stuff
}

// note: please use brackets consistently
if ((sentData == "ffff") && (sentAddr == "0000")) {
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
if ((sentData != "ffff") || (sentAddr != "0000")){
    // do stuff
}
```

---

**ADDENDUM:**

Your last edit to your question includes this statement:

> So if I use `sentData: fb8c sentAddr: 0000` in `if ((sentData != "ffff") && (sentAddr != "0000"))`
>   I get `if (TRUE && FALSE)`, but it still enters the if statement.

If by *"it still enters the if statement"* you mean that it takes the first branch, then you are wrong. In fact your output shows that it prints *"B &&. Same"*, which is the second branch (*else*).

Comment: I see it now ... don't know how I could have been so blind for that long. Thank you! I would up vote both answers, but sadly I cannot due to the reputation limit. Thank you again!

Answer (score 9):

You are incorrect in thinking that `!a && !b` is the opposite of `!(a && b)`.

This is because distributing or un-distributing a negation over a Boolean operation requires that you flip the Boolean operation to its dual as well as negate the individual inner terms, and vice versa.

This is known as [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), and is a fundamental law in Boolean algebra.

Therefore the dual of:

```
(a && b)
```

is actually:

```
(!a || !b)
```

And the dual of:

```
(!a && !b)
```

is actually:

```
(a || b)
```

Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    std::string sentData("ffff");
    std::string sentAddr("060C");

    auto a = (sentData == "ffff");  // true
    auto b = (sentAddr == "0000");  // false

    if (a)              cout << "A 1. Same" << endl;
    else                cout << "A 1. Different" << endl;

    if (b)              cout << "A 2. Same" << endl;
    else                cout << "A 2. Different" << endl;

    if (a && b)         cout << "A &&. Same" << endl;
    else                cout << "A &&. Different" << endl;

    if (!a)             cout << "B 1. Different" << endl;
    else                cout << "B 1. Same" << endl;

    if (!b)             cout << "B 2. Different" << endl;
    else                cout << "B 2. Same" << endl;

    if ((!a || !b))     cout << "B &&. Different" << endl;
    else                cout << "B &&. Same" << endl;
}
```

[See it live on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bb811558bf9f1aa)